# Defining a common initializer for an immutable type hierarchy

Tags: c#, design-patterns, immutability

I'd like to define an interface and abstract base class for a set of "Record" types.  Records are generally passed to/from another system that represents the record as a string.  Thus, each record class will need a `Parse(string str)` method and a `ToString()` method.  Record classes also need to define methods to compare for equality, as well as a few other common utility methods.  A sample record class without a common base might look like:

```
public class MyRecord : IEquatable<MyRecord>
{
    public string FieldA { get; private set; }
    public int FieldB { get; private set; }

    public MyRecord(string fieldA, int fieldB /* .. */) { }
    public static MyRecord Parse(string recordString) { /* .. */ }

    public override string ToString() { /* .. */  }
    public override int GetHashCode() { /* .. */ }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { /* .. */ }
    public bool Equals(MyRecord other) { /* .. */ }
}
```

It will simplify the usage scenarios if I can design the records as immutable.  The above class supports immutability by defining read-only properties, and doing all object initialization in the parameterized constructor or `Parse` method.  I have specifically not exposed the default constructor.

I'm having trouble applying this design to a base record class that concrete record types can inherit from.  Specifically, I need a general `Parse` method that can instantiate the derived type, without exposing a default constructor or partially-constructed objects.  The design I have so far looks like:

```
public interface IRecord { /* .. */ }

public abstract class RecordBase : IRecord
{
    public static TRecord Parse<TRecord>(string recordStr)
        where TRecord: RecordBase, new()
    {
        TRecord record = new TRecord();
        record.Initialize(recordStr);

        return record;
    }

    protected abstract void Initialize(string recordStr);
}

public class MyRecord : RecordBase, IEquatable<MyRecord>
{
    public string FieldA { get; private set; }
    public int FieldB { get; private set; }

    public MyRecord(string fieldA, int fieldB /* .. */) { /* .. */ }

    public override string ToString() { /* .. */  }
    public override int GetHashCode() { /* .. */ }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { /* .. */ }
    public bool Equals(MyRecord other) { /* .. */ }

    protected MyRecord() { }
    protected override void Initialize(string recordStr) { /* .. */ }
}
```

However the compiler complains when I try to call `RecordBase.Parse<MyRecord>(..)` because `MyRecord`'s default constructor is not exposed publicly.

So my question is:

- Is there a better design that will allow me to have immutable record types as well as a common `Parse` initializer?  Or is there an inherent flaw in trying to create an immutable type hierarchy with common initialization APIs at the base-class level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking SRP when adding parsing functions for your records.

1. Create a separate parser class.
2. Tag it with an attribute: [ParserFor(typeof(MyRecord))]
3. Create a ParserService class.
4. Use reflection to scan all loaded assemblies after types that has the ParserFor attribute.
5. Use the parser service to parse and create all records.

Comment: I like this idea, although I think relying on reflection would be overkill-- each record type will require exactly 1 parser.  Also, I consider `Parse()` and `ToString()` inverses of each other; should the `ToString()` go in the parser as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Factory Pattern (parse from data) and the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (for the clone/factory ability).

E.g.

```
abstract class Base<T> : IBase // IBase for common demoninator
{
    abstract T Parse(Stream data);
}

Derived : Base<Derived>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you promise to be very careful, you might be able to use [System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx). However, this using this method will need the guarantee that none of the IRecord.Parse implementations expect any field (at all) to be not null/0.

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction, in thinking of parsing more as deserialization from a string.  Perhaps I can take advantage of some existing serialization interfaces to help me here.

Comment: Actually I meant that method as a replacement for `TRecord record = new TRecord();`. It would then become `TRecord record = (TRecord) FormatServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TRecord));`. Deserialization has the 'disadvantage' that the string would need some type info baked in. Or you would need a God-method that could recognize the correct type based on the contents of the string.